# How to execute two reducers to update state

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, jestjs

I need to execute a `reducer` in order to change the `state`. I need this updated `state` for my second `reducer` to work. It relies on the changes made in the state. However, I am not sure how to update the `state` in a test first and then run the second `reducer` on it.

```
it('returns the correct sate', () => {
    const firstAction = {
        type: FOO,
        ...
    };

    const secondAction = {
        type: BAR,
        ...
    }

    reducer(undefined, firstAction); // <- Execute the first action
    expect(reducer(undefined, secondAction)) // <- throws an error because the values secondAction relies on are not there
        .toEqual(initialState
            ....);
});
```

That is not working as expected. `reducer(undefined, firstAction);` is not updating the state and `reducer(undefined, secondAction)` throws an error because the values it relies on to `update` the state are not there.

How do I update the state with an action in a test environment and then execute a second action on this updated reducer?

Comment: Did you take a look at the "Beyond combineReducers" section inside the Redux doc? https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/beyond-combinereducers#sharing-data-between-slice-reducers

Comment: @SamuelVaillant It is within the same reducer. `reducer(undefined, firstAction);` operates on the same `reducer` as `reducer(undefined, secondAction);` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reducers are pure function they take a `state` and an `action` and return the next `state`. The example you gave expect the state to have changes after the first `reducer` call. But it's a pure function it does not mutate the state it returns it. If the second call requires the first state produces by the first action you have to pass it to your reducer.

```
const stateAfterFirstAction = reducer(undefined, firstAction);
const stateAfterSecondAction = reducer(stateAfterFirstAction, secondAction);
```